# geodjango return geojson from raw SQL

Tags: python, django, geojson

have this django view: I am aware I can use this to serialize a postgres table to geojson

```
def mun_datasets(request):
    mun = serialize('geojson', Municipalities.objects.all())
    return HttpResponse(mun, content_type='json')
```

url.py

`url(r'^mun_data/$',mun_datasets, name = 'mun'),`

however I have a very complex query which needs to be in raw SQL so I am trying to figure out how to return geojson from a raw SQL query (the query below is very simple but the actual query is complex so I just want to know how to return geojson from any sql query to apply the concept to harder queries)

```
def mun_datasets(request):
   cur = conn.cursor()
   qry='''select json_object_agg(namelsad,geom) from reporter_municipalities'''
   cur.execute(qry)
   row=cur.fetchone()
   mun = serialize('geojson', row)
   return HttpResponse(mun, content_type='json')
```

this gives me an error on my `mun_data`url

```
AttributeError at /mun_data/
'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/mun_data/
Django Version: 1.11
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/gis/serializers/geojson.py in start_object, line 38
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.6.5
Python Path:    
['/home/ralph/Desktop/geo',
 '/usr/lib/python36.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/home/ralph/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 12 Oct 2018 14:00:44 +0000
```

created this query

```
SELECT row_to_json(fc)
          FROM
           ( SELECT 'FeatureCollection' AS TYPE,
                   array_to_json(array_agg(f)) AS features
           FROM
             (SELECT 'Feature' AS TYPE,
                     ST_AsGeoJSON(g.geom)::JSON AS geometry,            
                     row_to_json(
                                   (SELECT p
                                    FROM
                                      ( SELECT namelsad,geom) AS p)) AS properties
              FROM reporter_municipalities AS g
              ) AS f) AS fc;
```

which yields

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[-75.100728,40.638361],[-75.100497,40.638426],[-75.097664,40.639218],[-75.09661,40.639512],[-75.09135,40.640982],[-75.090844,40.641214],[-75.088537 (...)

row=cur.fetchone()
#mun = serialize('geojson', row[0])
return HttpResponse(row[0], content_type='json')
```

mun_data does not throw an error it just returns this

```
typefeatures
```

Comment: Where do you import `serialize()` from ?

Comment: `from django.core.serializers import serialize`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

figured it out

```
def mun_datasets(request):
   cur = conn.cursor()
   qry='''SELECT row_to_json(fc)
          FROM
           ( SELECT 'FeatureCollection' AS TYPE,
                   array_to_json(array_agg(f)) AS features
           FROM
             (SELECT 'Feature' AS TYPE,
                     ST_AsGeoJSON(g.geom)::JSON AS geometry,            
                     row_to_json(
                                   (SELECT p
                                    FROM
                                      ( SELECT namelsad,geom) AS p)) AS properties
              FROM reporter_municipalities AS g
              ) AS f) AS fc;
      '''
   cur.execute(qry)
   row=cur.fetchone()
   return JsonResponse(row[0])
```